# How to determine if my device supports USB Ethernet controller?

Tags: linux, kernel, usb-drivers, usb-peripherals

I'm about to purchase USB-OTG Ethernet controller, but I read what it doesn't work on all devices. Furthermore, I've read what this functionality depends on Linux kernel been compiled with Ethernet driver or without it. So my question is in the title: *how do I figure out the presence or absence of Ethernet driver in kernel?*

<sup>Please feel free to correct if my logic above has any flaws.</sup>

I know already what my device supports several classes of peripherals via USB-OTG, namely mice, keyboards, mass storage.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score -3):

1. Connect a USB 3.0 thumb drive (USB Mass Storage Device) to one of the Intel USB 3.0 ports
2. In Device Manager, click View, and click Devices by connection.
3. In Devices by connection view, you can easily see the USB Mass Storage device under the Intel® USB 3.0 extensible Host Controller category.

Comment: Device manager? On Android?